# Is it possible to set up my Apple Watch to show notifications for apps for which I have disabled notifications on my iPhone? If so, how?

Tags: notifications, apple-watch, watchos

I have disabled notifications for pretty much every app on my iPhone. But because the Watch represents a different context, I would like to have some of those apps show notifications on my Watch, while still being disabled on my iPhone.

Apparently this is not trivial to set up, if it even is a possibility. The Watch App on my iPhone offers the option of mirroring the phone’s notifications, but that’s not what I’m looking for.